# Memcached telnet output says zero active slabs

Tags: memcached

I am running `memcached 1.4.5` on `centos 5.10`, output from `telnet` is:

```
stats slabs  
STAT active_slabs 0   
STAT total_malloced 0  
END
```

and:

```
stats items
END

STAT cas_hits 0  
STAT cas_badval 0  
STAT auth_cmds 0  
STAT auth_errors 0  
STAT bytes_read 60  
STAT bytes_written 1633  
STAT limit_maxbytes 3221225472  
STAT accepting_conns 1  
STAT listen_disabled_num 0  
STAT threads 4  
STAT conn_yields 0  
STAT bytes 0  
STAT curr_items 0  
STAT total_items 0  
STAT evictions 0  
STAT reclaimed 0  
END  
stats slabs  
STAT active_slabs 0  
STAT total_malloced 0
```

I am seeing so many zeros in stats output must be something up!

Basically seems like `memcached` is running ok but giving no output so looks like its doing nothing.
I had this working correctly one time only now I get the above output even after restarting `memcached` and `apache`

Any advice greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you put anything into the cache?

Comment: i think so, i have i am trying to get it to cache php, [web-1 ~]# php -i | grep 11211
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211

Comment: Are you confusing Memcache with an PHP-opcode cache like APC, Xcache or OpCache

Comment: Ah right i see, thats right in that case, How can i get memcached to cache apace requests in that case? thanks